# Styling is not Working on option of datalist

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dropdown

I am trying to change background color of option on hover but I am not able to do that in `datalist`. Is there any way to achieve this? I tried by giving inline css, external css, by events (`onmouseover`, `onmouseenter`, `onmouseleave`)

```
/*  React Js Code */
<input  type="text" list="browsers" />

<datalist id="browsers">
/* iterating values from array and showing in option */
<option style={{backgroundColor:'red'}} onMouseOver={e=>e.target.style.color = 'green'}  onMouseEnter={(e)=>e.target.style.background = 'red'} 
onMouseLeave={(e)=>e.target.style.background = 'black'} >{d}</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can customise the datalist using CSS but you'll have to disable/ignore the OOB datalist functionality and rewrite the functionality using JavaScript and the result is below:

```js
input.onfocus = function() {
  browsers.style.display = 'block';
  input.style.borderRadius = "5px 5px 0 0";
};
for (let option of browsers.options) {
  option.onclick = function() {
    input.value = option.value;
    browsers.style.display = 'none';
    input.style.borderRadius = "5px";
  }
};

input.oninput = function() {
  currentFocus = -1;
  var text = input.value.toUpperCase();
  for (let option of browsers.options) {
    if (option.value.toUpperCase().indexOf(text) > -1) {
      option.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      option.style.display = "none";
    }
  };
}
var currentFocus = -1;
input.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    currentFocus++
    addActive(browsers.options);
  } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    currentFocus--
    addActive(browsers.options);
  } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (currentFocus > -1) {
      /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
      if (browsers.options) browsers.options[currentFocus].click();
    }
  }
}

function addActive(x) {
  if (!x) return false;
  removeActive(x);
  if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
  if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
  x[currentFocus].classList.add("active");
}

function removeActive(x) {
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #000;
  /*   border-bottom: none; */
}

datalist {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border-top: none;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 5px;
}

option {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 4px;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #eeeeee
}

option:hover,
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input autocomplete="off" role="combobox" list="" id="input" name="browsers">
<!-- Its important that you keep list attribute empty to hide the default dropdown icon and the browser's default datalist -->

<datalist id="browsers" role="listbox">
  <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
  <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
  <option value="Microsoft Edge">Microsoft Edge</option>
</datalist>
```

from [DEV](https://dev.to/siddev/customise-datalist-45p0)

Comment: Its not working , run this code into your editor (This is example code just to check working) pastebin.com/yfY3c3DX

Comment: so sorry, I edited the questions you can see

Comment: but you can convert it to react, JS is easier for me

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add a class to it and use css `:hover` method like:

```
<option className="my-option" />
```

and then in css just

```
.my-option:hover{
  background-color:'red';
}
```

Comment: Its not working , run this code into your editor (This is example code just to check working) https://pastebin.com/yfY3c3DX

Comment: Oh I see now... why don't you use normal select instead of input with datalist?

Comment: I needed to include search functionality in a dropdown because of high number of records , so the simpliest method i got is to implement datalist